# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ReactCurrentDispatcher') when trying to run a CRACO React app from a Vite React app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, vite, webpack-module-federation, craco

I have a pretty large React app that was created with CRA and subsequently had CRACO added to it. Working on this app is starting to get very tedious so I wish to try and break it up, incrementally, into micro-frontend apps. I wish to create a Host app that routes all traffic to the legacy app's routes as a start.

I have created the host app:

```
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import federation from '@originjs/vite-plugin-federation';
const deps = require('./package.json').dependencies;

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    federation({
      name: 'hostApp',
      remotes: {
        legacy_app: {
          external: 'http://localhost:3333/remoteEntry.js',
          format: 'var',
          externalType: 'url',
        }
      },
      shared: {
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        'react-dom': {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps['react-dom'],
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
});

// package.json
{
  "name": "host-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --port=5500 --strictPort",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview --port=5500 --strictPort"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation": "1.2.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "6.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.42",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.6",
    "@types/react-router": "5.1.20",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.3.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "3.1.0",
    "sass": "1.63.6",
    "vite": "4.3.9"
  }
}
```

And here is the config of the legacy app:

```
// modulefederation.config.js
const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;

module.exports = {
    name: "legacy_app",
    filename: "remoteEntry.js",
    exposes: {
        "./App": "./src/App",
    },
    shared: {
        react: {
            singleton: true,
            requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        "react-dom": {
            singleton: true,
            requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
        },
    },
};

// .cracorc.js (some options omitted for brevity)
const cracoModuleFederation = require('craco-module-federation');

module.exports = ({ env }) => {
    return {
        plugins: [
            {
                plugin: cracoModuleFederation,
            },
        ]
    }
};

// package.json
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
```

And finally, the App.tsx of the host app:

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";

const LegacyApp = lazy(() => import("legacy_cra/App"));

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/*",
    element: <LegacyApp/>,
  },
  {
    path: "/foo",
    element: <div>Hello world!</div>,
  }
]);

function App() {
  return (
    <Suspense>
      <RouterProvider router={router}></RouterProvider>
    </Suspense>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I run this, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ReactCurrentDispatcher')
    at react-jsx-runtime.development.js:328:1
    at ./node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.development.js (react-jsx-runtime.development.js:1313:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/react/jsx-runtime.js (jsx-runtime.js:6:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/App.tsx (ErrorComponents.module.scss:13:1)
(anonymous) @ react-jsx-runtime.development.js:328
./node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.development.js @ react-jsx-runtime.development.js:1313
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:62
./node_modules/react/jsx-runtime.js @ jsx-runtime.js:6
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:62
./src/App.tsx @ ErrorComponents.module.scss:13
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:62
(anonymous) @ container-entry:3
(anonymous) @ __x00__virtual:__federation__:82
```

From what I can understand it can happen because the react and react-dom versions between the two don't match, but I don't think that's it.